# How to give box shadow for rect in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have used highcharts renderer rect for draw a rectangle in chart. I tried to apply **"box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #CF9100, 0 0 30px #CF9100;"** for rect by using attr and css elements in chart, but rect is not support this boxshadow. 
Can any one help me for how to apply above boxShadow property to renderer rect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve similar effect by using `defs` property: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

Example with rendered rectangle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/cavmg1aq/